# How to forward declare an alias without knowing the actual implementation?

Tags: c++, alias, using, forward-declaration

I'm using a *Bridge* pattern where the interface forward-declares an `Impl` class without knowing it's definition. The class definition uses just a pointer to this implementation, so no definition is needed here:

```cpp
// interface.h

class Interface1 {
public:
    void method();
private:
    class Impl;
    Impl *impl;
};

class Interface2 {
public:
    void method();
private:
    class Impl;
    Impl *impl;
};
```

The client code uses these interfaces without knowing the implementations as well:

```cpp
// client.cpp

#include <interface.h>

void useInterface1() {
    Interface1 obj;
    obj.method();
}
```

The actual bridge from each interface to its implementation is defined in a *cpp* file:

```cpp
// bridge.cpp

#include <interface.h>
#include <implementation.h>

void Interface1::method() {
    impl->method();
}

void Interface2::method() {
    impl->method();
}
```

Now I can define the implementations:

```cpp
// implementation.h

#include <interface.h>

class Interface1::Impl {
public:
    void method() {}
};

class Interface2::Impl {
public:
    void method() {}
};
```

As you can see, the implementations are two distinct classes, but they are similar. What I want to do is to define a single class `Implementation` and make `InterfaceX::Impl` aliases of this class. Something like this (this is just a pseudocode that doesn't compile):

```cpp
class Interface1 {
    // Use the name `Impl` here without knowing what stands behind this name:
    using Impl;
    Impl *impl;
};

class Implementation {
    // ...
};

// Define the InterfaceX::Impl classes either as separate classes or as aliases:
using Interface1::Impl = Implementation;
using Interface2::Impl = Implementation;
```

How can I do that? Please note that the implementation cannot be a template parameter of the interface because in this case the implementation shall be known to the client code.

Comment: You maybe should look for the Couriously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP).

Comment: I know of CRTP, and what I'm doing looks similar to that. The main difference is that CRTP exposes the implementation to the client code: `class Implementation : public Interface<Implementation>;`. In my case the client code has no clue what the implementation is.

Comment: How about `struct MyImpl {void method(){}}; struct Interface1::Impl : MyImpl {}; struct Interface2::Impl : MyImpl {};`?

Comment: @Jarod42 that is what I've done now. But this solution doesn't solve all the problems. To construct the object of type `Interface1` I need to create an instance of the implementation `Interface1::Impl`, as this is what the class expects in the constructor. The same for `Interface2`. I need a single method that returns both `Interface1::Impl` and `Interface2::Impl` at the same time, and not the base for them.